# Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax-error

Here is the JSFidle to the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/LRTh3/36/

```
$('div.boxes').mousedown(function (event) {

    // Error on this line
    var inner_box = $(".box").is(":hover");

    if ( inner_box == true ) {

        alert("blue,gree,pink was clicked");
    }

    else alert("You mousedowned on the red box");

});​

console: Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover
```

Works if only **one** ".box" layer is presented. Is this a bug? How would I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('div.boxes').mousedown(function (event) {

// Error on this line
var $target = $(event.target);    
if (  $target.is(".box")) {

    alert("blue,gree,pink was clicked");
}

else alert("You mousedowned on the red box");


});​
```

I lifted it from [jQuery API doc](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Comment: You should explain what was wrong here. I needed some time to figure out what is what here even when I've got same problem. Sorry, but -1