# In IE7 browser jQuery v1.7.1 show syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

In my website i am using jquery v1.7.1 
In other browsers(IE9,IE8) it works fine But in IE7 it showing the following  Syntax error.

```
SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover 
jquery.min.js, line 3 character 14659
```

If you guys have any idea about this please tel me to fix this.

Comment: upgrade jquery to 1.9 and don't use ie7

Comment: That's why jquery 1.8 been developed and now 1.9. Upgrade the jquery.

Comment: @jai,@salexch If i change to jqueryv1.9.0 i am getting this error SCRIPT5022: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: unsupported pseudo: hover 
jquery.min.js, line 2 character 24501

Comment: `hover()` is no longer supported as a synonym for `mouseenter()` and `mouseleave()` as mentioned in one of the removed features in `jquery v1.9`.

be aware if you are working with new latest version of jquery and using `hover()`.

Comment: If you get errors like that, you should switch to the development (uncompressed) package for the version of jQuery you're using to help you track down the specific error. Then give us the more specific error and the context in which it occurs. Consider using breakpoints to narrow this down, or view the stack trace in your javascript debug console.

Comment: @Razor - Where do you see that `.hover()` was removed? Perhaps you meant `:hover` (http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12736)?

Comment: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11120 -- Seems to describe the issue perfectly. If it is in fact the same issue.

Comment: post a link to your code ([pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), [codepen](http://codepen.io), [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/)) and you'll get some useful answers.

Answer (score 2):

According to jQuery [Ticket #11120](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11120) this happens if you have a selector that begins or ends with a TAB character, unless the selector also includes a class name. Check all your selectors and make sure none of them contain TAB.

Comment: This is what it ended up being.  Incredible find.  Thank you.

Comment: Thanks should really go to @BrandonBearden, who mentioned it in a comment, but didn't go into detail about the cause.

Answer (score 1):

It's because you have a syntax error in your script.  Since you didn't provide a script, I can't tell you what the syntax error is, but you might want to look at:

- [Ticket #11120: Tabs in some selectors break in IE7](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11120) (bug in jQuery 1.7.1 fixed in 1.8)
- ["Neither :focus nor :hover are supported selectors in jQuery"](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6881)
- [Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: hover](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10704183/712765)
- [" there's no decent way to support the :hover selector on browsers that don't have it natively.... The jQuery API documentation does not list it so it is not a selector that we promise will work cross-browser."](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/4434)

Comment: Assume no syntax error that appears in browsers later than IE7.  IE7 does have support for hover pseudos.  In order for this to be an accepted answer, it would help to see an alternative solution rather than simply ideas why it might be happening.

Comment: "Alternative" to what? In order to give you a non-insulting answer I would have to know what you are trying to do and how you are trying to do it in order to give you an alternative to it.  For starters, upgrade to jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: Upgrading, as I'm sure you know, isn't an option in every situation.  We've combed code to remove any and all references to pseudo selectors.  If no alternative can be provided due to lack of code (as posting a full codebase full of possibilities isn't feasible), then ideas why it might be occurring in a browser in that supports hover (as IE7 does in standards mode, as is present in this application - html5 doctype applied).  What I'm searching for is someone proficient enough to explain a situation with possible alternatives to get around this issue.  Hopefully this clears it up for you.

Comment: Call stack isn't indicative of any particular location, and loops back every time to a general selector with no pseudo present - hover or otherwise.  Error occurs multiple times per page.  The only pseudos present belong to our CSS files, which utilize most every pseudo in CSS3, from :visited to :first-line.  Hopefully a bit more background might spark some insight.

Comment: @Josh, switch from `jquery.min.js` to `jquery.js` and post the code around where the syntax error is occurring.

Answer (score 0):

check all your objects, maybe there is a trailing comma after last property..

```
...
},    
lastProperty: true,
```

then remove it..